# For a compact Riemannian manifold $M$, for sup, inf, the condition of laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $0<u \in C^{\infty}(M)$, with compact Riemannian manifold $M$,  then i want to prove two following facts

(i) Since $M$ is compact, there exist $x_0 \in M$ such that $u(x_0) = \sup_{M} u$, then $\Delta u(x_0) \leq 0$

(ii) Since $M$ is compact, there exist $x_0 \in M$ such that $u(x_0) = \inf_{M} u$, then $\Delta u(x_0) \geq 0$

How one can prove this statement?

Comment: You need to have a Riemannian manifold to define the laplacian. Check this out:  http://math.arizona.edu/~dido/colbois-course.pdf

Comment: Thanks @ncmathsadist, I edit my question. Above things were used in my Riemannian geometry class to prove some conformal metric are indeed identical in some certain condition.